# regex for dimension

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expresion for dimensions it must match sing or double digit that has an x and or a space and end with mm|cm|mtr|ft

my example doesn't work

```
/\d+(\.\d+)?\s{0,1}[xX]\s{0,1}\d+(\.\d+)?(\s*[xX]\s{0,1}\d+(\.\d+))?\s{1}(mm|cm|inches|meters|feet)/

-120x200mm //not a match
100\' X 130\' // not a match
12x12.3x12 not a match
12x.12.3x12mm match
12.2x12x12cm match
12x12x12ft match
```

http://regexr.com/3f2vb

Comment: What kind of dimension is this `12x.12.3x12` (two periods) ?

Comment: dimension is width height and depth

Comment: I am talking about `.12.3` is it a number ?

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/5KHfGU/1? Your regex doesn't have `ft` and is allowing for more then 2 leading integers. (I also assumed `.12.3` was a typo)

Comment: Try this `/-?(\d+(?:\*.\d+)?(\'\s*x\s-?)?)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\\4)?)(\'|mm|cm|inches|meters|feet|ft|"?)/g` maybe helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking:

```
(?<!-)((\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*[xX]\s*){2}\d+(\.\d+)?\s*(mm|cm|mtrs|ft|yd)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xK7VYT/3)

**Edit:**

For both 2 and 3 dimensions:

[**Demo2**](https://regex101.com/r/xK7VYT/4)

```
(?<!-)(\d+(\.\d+)?)(\s*[xX]\s*\d+(\.\d+)?){1,2}\s*(mm|cm|mtrs|ft|yd)
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help

Comment: Note `\d+` is more than 1 or 2 digits.